# Set Sequelize#belongsTo() to not accept null reference

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, model-associations

Using Sequelize#belongsTo() with no options generates a constraint that accepts a NULL reference. How can I change it to only accept a valid object?

Tried searching all available options for the Associations methods, but didn't find anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I think the only way you could accomplish this is by:

```
ChildTable.belongsTo(ParentTable, {
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
    foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false
    }
});
```